# Tabbar application in iphone

Tags: iphone

i am making an application in which am creating 5 tabbars in iDocViewController view. the problem is that when we are shifting control from disclaimer viewcontroller to idocviewcontroller tabbar. how'll i set focus on idocviewcontroller tabbar. how'll i get rid of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int desiredTabIndex = // the tab's index within tabBars.viewControllers array
   tabBar.selectedIndex = desiredTabIndex;